# Powerset Function 1-Liner

Tags: haskell

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#error) demonstrates the `powerset` function:

> The `powerset` of some set is a set of all subsets of that set.

```
powerset :: [a] -> [[a]]  
powerset xs = filterM (\x -> [True, False]) xs
```

And running it:

```
ghci> powerset [1,2,3]                    
[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,3],[1],[2,3],[2],[3],[]]
```

What's going on here? I see `filterM`'s signature (shown below), but I don't understand how it's executing.

`filterM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]`

Please walk me through this `powerset` function.

Comment: Perhaps you should try a little yourself?  What is `m` in this example?  What does `filterM` turn into if you expand the monadic operations?

Comment: http://byorgey.wordpress.com/2007/06/26/deducing-code-from-types-filterm/

Comment: good point @augustss. good link, DaoWen. I'm going to try to implement `filterM` now.

Comment: there's a discussion about this [on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/225f0/beautiful_haskell_implementation_of_maths_power).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
powerset ::                                    [a] -> [[a]]  
powerset xs = filterM (\x -> [True, False])    xs
                             -------------            -----
filterM :: Monad m => (a  -> m Bool       ) -> [a] -> m [a]
-- filter  ::         (a ->    Bool       ) -> [a] ->   [a]   (just for comparison)
                             -------------            -----
                             m Bool ~ [Bool]          m ~ []
```

So this is `filter` "in" the nondeterminism (list) monad.

Normally, filter keeps only those elements in its input list for which the predicate holds.

Nondeterministically, we get all the possibilities of keeping the elements for which the nondeterministic predicate might hold, and removing those for which it might not hold. Here, it is so for any element, so we get all the possibilities of keeping, or removing, an element.

Which is a powerset.

---

Another example (in a different monad), building on the one in [Brent Yorgey's blog post](http://byorgey.wordpress.com/2007/06/26/deducing-code-from-types-filterm/) mentioned in the comments,

```
  >> filterM (\x-> if even x then Just True else Nothing) [2,4..8]
Just [2,4,6,8]
  >> filterM (\x-> if even x then Just True else Nothing) [2..8]
Nothing
  >> filterM (\x-> if even x then Just True else Just False) [2..8]
Just [2,4,6,8]
```

---

Let's see how this is actually achieved, with code. We'll define

```
filter_M :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
filter_M p []     = return []
filter_M p (x:xs) = p x >>= (\b ->
                if b
                    then filter_M p xs >>= (return . (x:))
                    else filter_M p xs )
```

Writing out the list monad's definitions for `return` and bind (`>>=`) (i.e. `return x = [x]`, `xs >>= f = concatMap f xs`), this becomes

```
filter_L :: (a -> [Bool]) -> [a] -> [[a]]
filter_L p [] = [[]]
filter_L p (x:xs) -- = (`concatMap` p x) (\b->
                  --     (if b then map (x:) else id) $ filter_L p xs )
                  -- which is semantically the same as
                  --     map (if b then (x:) else id) $ ... 
   = [ if b then x:r else r | b <- p x, r <- filter_L p xs ]
```

Hence,

```
-- powerset = filter_L    (\_ -> [True, False])
--            filter_L :: (a  -> [Bool]       ) -> [a] -> [[a]]
powerset :: [a] -> [[a]]
powerset [] = [[]]
powerset (x:xs) 
   = [ if b then x:r else r | b <- (\_ -> [True, False]) x, r <- powerset xs ]
   = [ if b then x:r else r | b <- [True, False], r <- powerset xs ]
   = map (x:) (powerset xs) ++ powerset xs    -- (1)
   -- or, with different ordering of the results:
   = [ if b then x:r else r | r <- powerset xs, b <- [True, False] ]
   = powerset xs >>= (\r-> [True,False] >>= (\b-> [x:r|b] ++ [r|not b]))
   = powerset xs >>= (\r-> [x:r,r])
   = concatMap (\r-> [x:r,r]) (powerset xs)   -- (2)
   = concat [ [x:r,r] | r <- powerset xs  ]
   = [ s | r <- powerset xs, s <- [x:r,r] ]
```

and we have thus derived the two usual implementations of `powerset` function.

The flipped order of processing is made possible by the fact that the predicate is constant (`const [True, False]`). Otherwise the test would be evaluated over and over again for the same input value, and we probably wouldn't want that.

Comment: so how exactly does passing in `\x -> [True, False]` mean "show all possibilities of this list, i.e. powerset?

Comment: no. "show all possibilities of" is how the *nondetermnism monad* operates. It is achieved by defining `join xss = concat xss`, i.e. defining `xs >>= f = concatMap f xs`. Any singleton list represents a nondeterministic entity with one possible value. A two-elements list represents a non-deterministic entity with two possible values. In "true" nondeterminism we imagine it holding these values simultaneously; in real computers this may be implemented by two values which are explored sequentially, i.e. a list. Which is the same, in Prolog.

Comment: and an empty list represents no possible values. That's what the title of that famous paper by P. Wadler alludes to, "How to replace failure by a list of successes" - each element of a list represents successful computation of that value, so empty list represents a failure to compute any values. (the "pattern matching" terminology in that paper refers to parsing, not pattern matching as in Haskell).

Comment: Watch out! The definition you give for `filter_M` looks like it has a serious efficiency problem in the list monad. Specifically, I don't think common tails are shared. What you want, I think, is `let rest=filter_M p xs in p x >>= (\b -> ...)`. Now it's possible that compiler optimizations might be able to save you, but I wouldn't want to count on that.

Comment: @dfeuer on the other hand sometimes it might be better to recalculate than to memoize, esp. when the list is very large. That's why I wrote version (1) of `powerset` that way.

Comment: I'm not sure you're right about that. You have to hold the whole list in either case, and I'm pretty sure it's better to go back to front than the other way around—that is, to build everything *ending* with a given suffix before moving on to the next, instead of building everything *starting* with a given prefix. This is *not* the case for `permutations`, but `powerset` is much better behaved.

Comment: @dfeuer to hold the whole resulting list, or the whole input list, is very big difference in size, here. With your suggestion we get `filter_L p (x:xs) = let rest=filter_L p xs in [r | b <- p x, r<- if b then map (x:) rest else rest]`, and from one `b` to the next we've generated the whole `rest` while holding on to it. Same for (1), if we'd use `let r=powerset xs in ...` or if CSE kicks in. (2) doesn't have this problem, but we only get (2) if we flip the order of processing, as if it was defined `filterM p (x:xs) = do { ys  <- filterM p xs; flg <- p x; return (if flg then x:ys else ys) }`.

Comment: I'm a little too tired to think about this in depth, but the library actually defines it thus:
`filterM p (x:xs) =  do {flg <- p x; ys  <- filterM p xs; return (if flg then x:ys else ys)`

Comment: @dfeuer and my `filter_M` is the same as the standard [`filterM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/Control-Monad.html#filterM) in that respect, it just replaces its (equivalent of) `map (if b then (x:) else id) $ ...` with arguably more efficient `if b then map (x:) else id) $ ...`.

Comment: a post on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/225f0/beautiful_haskell_implementation_of_maths_power/c22c1y) seems to concur about (1) running in constant space.

Answer (score 8):

let me help you about this:

- **first**: you have to understand the **list monad**. If you remember, we have:

  ```
  do
    n  <- [1,2]  
    ch <- ['a','b']  
    return (n,ch)
  ```

  The result will be: `[(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'a'),(2,'b')]`

  Because: `xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)` and `return x = [x]`

  ```
  n=1: concat (map (\ch -> return (n,ch)) ['a', 'b'])
       concat ([ [(1,'a')], [(1,'b')] ]
       [(1,'a'),(1,'b')]
  and so forth ...
  the outermost result will be:
       concat ([ [(1,'a'),(1,'b')], [(2,'a'),(2,'b')] ])
       [(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'a'),(2,'b')]
  ```
- **second**: we have the implementation of filterM:

  ```
  filterM _ []     =  return []
  filterM p (x:xs) =  do
      flg <- p x
      ys  <- filterM p xs
      return (if flg then x:ys else ys)
  ```

  Let do an example for you to grasp the idea easier:

  ```
  filterM (\x -> [True, False]) [1,2,3]
  p is the lambda function and (x:xs) is [1,2,3]
  ```

  The innermost recursion of filterM: x = 3

  ```
  do
    flg <- [True, False]
    ys  <- [ [] ]
    return (if flg then 3:ys else ys)
  ```

  You see the similarity, like the example above we have:

  ```
  flg=True: concat (map (\ys -> return (if flg then 3:ys else ys)) [ [] ])
            concat ([ return 3:[] ])
            concat ([ [ [3] ] ])
            [ [3] ]
  and so forth ...
  the final result: [ [3], [] ]
  ```

  Likewise:

  ```
  x=2:
    do
      flg <- [True, False]
      ys  <- [ [3], [] ]
      return (if flg then 2:ys else ys)
  result: [ [2,3], [2], [3], [] ]
  x=1:
    do
      flg <- [True, False]
      ys  <- [ [2,3], [2], [3], [] ]
      return (if flg then 1:ys else ys)
  result: [ [1,2,3], [1,2], [1,3], [1], [2,3], [2], [3], [] ]
  ```
- **theoretically**: it's just chaining list monads after all:

  ```
  filterM :: (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
             (a -> [Bool]) -> [a] -> [ [a] ]
  ```

And that's all, hope you enjoy :D

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand `filterM`'s for the list monad (as is in your example) is to consider the following alternative pseudo-code'ish definition of `filterM`

```
filterM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
filterM p [x1, x2, .... xn] = do
                  b1 <- p x1
                  b2 <- p x2
                  ...
                  bn <- p xn
                  let element_flag_pairs = zip [x1,x2...xn] [b1,b2...bn]
                  return [ x | (x, True) <- element_flag_pairs]
```

With this definition of `filterM` you can easily see why the power-set is generated in your example.

For the sake of completeness, you might be also interested in how `foldM` and `mapM` can be defined as above

```
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [ b ]
mapM f [x1, x2, ... xn] = do
                   y1 <- f x1
                   y2 <- f x2
                   ...
                   yn <- f xn
                   return [y1,y2,...yn]

foldM :: Monad m => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> [ a ] -> m b
foldM _ a [] = return a
foldM f a [x1,x2,..xn] = do
               y1 <- f a x1
               y2 <- f y1 x2
               y3 <- f y2 x3
               ...
               yn <- f y_(n-1) xn
               return yn
```

Hope this helps!