# Understanding filterM

Tags: haskell, monads

Consider

```
filterM (\x -> [True, False]) [1, 2, 3]
```

I just cannot understand the magic that Haskell does with this `filterM` use case. The source code for this function is listed below:

```
filterM          :: (Monad m) => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
filterM _ []     =  return []
filterM p (x:xs) =  do
    flg <- p x
    ys  <- filterM p xs
    return (if flg then x:ys else ys)
```

With this use case, `p` should be the lambda function `(\x -> [True, False])`, and the first `x` should be `1`. So what does `flg <- p x` return? What exactly is the value of `flg` for each recursion?

Comment: This question is quite similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476248/powerset-function-1-liner but it doesn't focus so much on the body of `filterM` so I don't think it's an exact duplicate.

Comment: `filterM (\x->[True,False]) xs` means, roughly: for each element of `xs` non-deterministically take it or drop it. The result should be the list of all sub-lists of `xs` (having length `2 ^ length xs`).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The list monad `[]` models *non-determinism*: a list of values `[a]` represents a number of different possibilities for the value of `a`.

When you see a statement like `flg <- p x` in the list monad, `flg` will take on each value of `p x` in turn, i.e. `True` and then `False` in this case. The rest of the body of `filterM` is then executed twice, once for each value of `flg`.

To see how this happens in more detail, you need to understand the desugaring of `do` notation and the implementation of the `(>>=)` operator for the list monad.

`do` notation gets desugared line-by-line into calls to the `(>>=)` operator. For example the body of the non-empty `filterM` case turns into

```
p x >>= \flg -> (filterM p xs >>= \ys -> return (if flg then x:ys else ys))
```

This is completely mechanical as it's in essence just replacing `flg <-` before the expression with `>>= \flg ->` after the expression. In reality pattern-matching makes this a little more complicated, but not much.

Next is the actual implementation of `(>>=)`, which is a member of the `Monad` type class and has a different implementation for each instance. For `[]`, the type is:

```
(>>=) :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]
```

and the implementation is something like

```
[] >>= f = []
(x:xs) >>= f = f x ++ (xs >>= f)
```

So the loop happens in the body of `(>>=)`. This is all in a library, no compiler magic beyond the desugaring of the `do` notation.

An equivalent definition for `(>>=)` is

```
 xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)
```

which may also help you see what's happening.

The same thing then happens for the recursive call to `filterM`: for each value of `flg`, the recursive call is made and produces a list of results, and the final `return` statement is executed for each element `ys` in this list of result.

This "fan-out" on each recursive call leads to `2^3 = 8` elements in the final result of `filterM (\x -> [True, False]) [1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: @xingmu1978: Actually, that's the magic behind `instance Monad []` and `>>=`, so if you're interested in the details, have a look at a list monad tutorial.

Comment: p x >>= \flg -> (filterM p xs >>= \ps -> return (if flg then x:ys else ys))    'ps' should be 'ys', right?

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty straightforward, after we've put it all down on paper (someone smart once gave this advice: don't try doing it all in your head, put it all on paper!):

```
filterM          :: (Monad m) => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
filterM _ []     =  return []
filterM p (x:xs) =  do { flg <- p x
                       ; ys  <- filterM p xs
                       ; return (if flg then x:ys else ys) }

-- filterM (\x -> [True, False]) [1, 2, 3]
g [x,y,z] = filterM (\x -> [True, False]) (x:[y,z])
          = do {
                 flg <- (\x -> [True, False]) x
               ; ys  <- g [y,z]
               ; return ([x | flg] ++ ys) }
         = do {
                flg <- [True, False]               -- no `x` here!
              ; ys  <- do { flg2 <- (\x -> [True, False]) y
                          ; zs  <- g [z]
                          ; return ([y | flg2] ++ zs) }
              ; return ([x | flg] ++ ys) }
         = do {
                flg  <- [True, False]
              ; flg2 <- [True, False]
              ; zs   <- do { flg3 <- (\x -> [True, False]) z
                           ; s  <- g []
                           ; return ([z | flg3] ++ s) }
              ; return ([x | flg] ++ [y | flg] ++ zs) }
         = do {
                flg  <- [True, False]
              ; flg2 <- [True, False]
              ; flg3 <- [True, False]
              ; s    <- return []
              ; return ([x | flg] ++ [y | flg2] ++ [z | flg3] ++ s) }
```

The unnesting of the nested `do` blocks follows from the Monad laws.

Thus, in pseudocode:

```
    filterM (\x -> [True, False]) [1, 2, 3]
    =
      for flg in [True, False]:    -- x=1
          for flg2 in [True, False]:     -- y=2
              for flg3 in [True, False]:     -- z=3
                  yield ([1 | flg] ++ [2 | flg2] ++ [3 | flg3])
```